# Is there a NumPy like library for set computations?

Tags: python, performance, numpy, set

For fast numerical computations I often use NumPy. Despite NumPy being a great tool, it is (obviously) not a good choice for set operations, since NumPy works with arrays. Even Python's built-in set objects work a lot faster than using NumPy for set operations:

---

Preparation:

```
# NumPy arrays
a = np.unique(np.random.randint(0, high=1000, size=1000))
b = np.unique(np.random.randint(0, high=1000, size=1000))

# Python's built-in set objects
sa = set(a)
sb = set(b)
```

---

**Set intersection**:

```
# NumPy
timeit.timeit("np.intersect1d(a, b)", setup="from __main__ import a, b, np", number=10000)
> 1.3161415259819478

# Python
timeit.timeit("sa.intersection(sb)", setup="from __main__ import sa, sb", number=10000)
> 0.2791759959945921
```

**Set difference**:

```
# NumPy
timeit.timeit("np.setdiff1d(a, b)", setup="from __main__ import a, b, np", number=10000)
> 0.6135410660062917

# Python
timeit.timeit("sa - sb", setup="from __main__ import sa, sb", number=10000)
> 0.21169587498297915
```

**Set union**:

```
# NumPy
timeit.timeit("np.union1d(a, b)", setup="from __main__ import a, b, np", number=10000)
> 0.4114252869854681

# Python
timeit.timeit("sa.union(sb)", setup="from __main__ import sa, sb", number=10000)
> 0.2402713909978047
```

Of course this is rather unrepresentative, because `a` and `b` contain random integers...but I've tested this multiple times, also with ranges. NumPy was always something like 1.5 to 6x slower than Python's built-in set objects.

Moreover, I guess NumPy's arrays aren't great when elements have to be added or removed often.

---

**Problem**: I am currently working with sets that typically contain more than 10,000 elements, sometimes even millions of elements. Additionally, I am adding or removing elements quite often.

**Question:** Is there some kind of library available for fast set operations in Python? Some library that offers an API to pre-compiled stuff for set operations, like NumPy does for arrays / numerical operations?

Comment: line 519 in https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/5d062f3e2a29a8da9e8bbc654e86a9df62b20592/numpy/lib/arraysetops.py ...  uses in1d ... a lot is going on there ... to quote... "equivalent to ``np.array([item in b for item in a])     However, this idea fails if `ar2` is a set, or similar (non-sequence) .."  etc etc

Comment: Python `set` is based on hashing, just like its dictionaries.  `numpy` set like operations generally use sorting of regular arrays.  Given how central dictionaries are to Python code (namespace, objects) it shouldn't be surprising that its `sets` perform well.

Comment: @hpaulj true. However, Python's sets are slow for large amounts of data. Thus, a wrapper like NumPy delivering for example C implementations for fast set operations would be nice.

Comment: What kinds of objects in your sets?  Integers? General Python objects and classes (mutuable/immutables), array like buffers?  Database programs handle various forms of set operations (e.g. joins).

Comment: Integers or Strings (of a length <= 50).

Comment: Numpy setops are implemented in pure numpy without extensions, and typically make quite a few passes over the dataset of O(n); implementing similar algorithms but with loop fusion should remove that overhead, but afaik there are no existing libraries for that, no.